# Socket connect returns errno ETIMEOUT

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, ssl, epoll

I have one Tcp/Ip with ssl server enabled with epoll so it can handle ten thousand connections simultaneously. When i tried to test the server,i created thousand clients using thread. when i tried to connect with the server,after certain time connect() return ETIMEOUT. How to overcome this error?

Comment: Assuming the server actually calls accept, you'll need to provide much more info to get any help.

Comment: You created a **thousand** threads?

Comment: Yes i created thousand threads so that thousand clients connect to server simultaneously.

Comment: I'd say the server hit a resouce limit.

Comment: How do you know your server can handle ten thousand connections simultaneously?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could change the socket attributes for recv and xmit timeout values  Probably the same way you set the keepalive attribute